# Linking option while installing Linux

Tags: kernel

I have installed Linux kernel from source. The way I do this  is that   I first do     `make menuconfig` and then `make` inside the root directory of the source code.

As a result of this I get a an image file which I have to run.  My question is do I have control over linking also?  make would do both compilation and linking. What I want is just compile and stop, then inspect the compiled files, and then issue command for linking, finally generating the image.

Is it possible, how?

Comment: I am not saying 'image' being linked. See normally when you build a C program, it is first compiled by the compiler and then finally linked by a program called linker.  Does that also happen in case of Linux building?

Comment: It is possible by editing the `Makefile` but it doesn't make sense because you don't loose any files that were needed for linking.

Comment: The image is composed of statically linked objects, I guess, but as bercsh points out all those object files are still there.  They won't be any different before they are compiled/linked together into an executable. **Nothing is erased during the build,** and linking does not change the pieces.

Answer (score 2):

It would be quite some work to edit the multitude of makefiles responsible for building the kernel to omit linking steps and the way the kernel is built you may not get a full build if you attempt this.

As mentioned by bersch and goldilocks in the comments, the interim and final linking steps are just putting .o files together into the necessary objects.  You are able to do your inspections of the compiled objects as-is with no modification to the build (although linking is still happening) because the interim objects are not deleted.

If you browse a kernel source tree that you have called `make` in to build a kernel, you can find any `.o` file in the same directory as its corresponding source file.  You just need to identify the file you are interested in inspecting and find it.

For example, if we look at files in the `kernel/` directory, we can find

```
acct.c
acct.o
async.c
async.o
audit.c
auditfilter.c
auditfilter.o
audit.h
audit.o
auditsc.c
auditsc.o
```

and the `.o` files here are the objects that are later linked.  These are what you are trying to inspect and they are there if you built the kernel.

Note that this isn't exactly the process you were hoping for but short of spending a lot of time to learn the kernel build makefiles (they are big and not entirely intuitive) this is probably your best option to accomplish what you really want, to inspect the compiled files.  If you are unhappy with one of the objects you can change its source file and re-issue the `make` command and in essence this gives you the same results as what you were asking to accomplish.